# time pass algorithm in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import time
import random
info = """welcome to contest!..
pls answer question as quick as possible you can
pls enter small letter...\n"""
print(info)
questions = {"2 * 2 ?":"4",
"what is the capital city of turkey?":"ankara",
"what is the king of jungle?":"lion",
"what is the meaning of book in turkish language?":"kitap",
"who is the foundation of turkish government":"atatürk",
"what is the most popular drink in turkey?":"raki",
"pls tell us a hero as comic":"temel"}
correct = 0
wrong = 0
blank = 0
current_time = time.time() #system time
allowed_time = 25 #total time to reply the question 

for i in random.sample(list(questions), 5):
     question = questions[i]
     if time.time() < current_time+allowed_time:
         answer = input("1. soru --> {} : ".format(i))
     if answer == question:
         correct += 1
     elif answer == "":
         blank += 1
     else:
         wrong += 1
print()
print("right answer  :", correct)
print("wrong answer :", wrong)
print("blank answer :", blank)
```

Please see my survey code above. It's selecting random 5 question in total time 25 seconds. But, I'd like to make it time option for every single question.
For example, questions must be replied with in ten seconds otherwise change question automatically.

Could you help on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

here's the steps to proceed(algorithm):

1. Add a timer to each question.

> Run a counter or a timer inside the for loop, then, for every iteration passed, store the time in a variable x, check if x is less than 10.

2. Check whether it is answered within 10 seconds.

> Iterate to the Next question, this i+1.

3. If NOT, jump to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` function - by its definition - waits for the input *infinitely*. Probably there is no cross-platform solution for it.

For `*nix` operating systems you may do this:

Create *another thread with the timer* which will *interrupt the main thread* after some time limit.

You may define a function for your input which will do it:

```
import thread      # _thread for Python 3.x
import threading

def timed_input(prompt, timeout=25.):
    timer = threading.Timer(timeout, thread.interrupt_main)
    answer = ""
    try:
        timer.start()
        answer = input(prompt)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    timer.cancel()
    return answer
```

and then use it instead of the standard `input()` function in your code (and of course without your original attempts with the `time` module).

Comment: thank you so much, when i try your solution, for overepassed time no answer printed screen but question not renewed by programme automatically

Answer (score 0):

Probably the *most simple* and the *most elegant* (from the programmer's point of view) is simply to keep infinitely time for an answer *but then reject it* if it was answered after the given time limit:

```
 start_time = time.time()     
 answer = input("1. soru --> {} : ". format(i))
 if time.time() - start_time > allowed_time:
     # code for rejecting the answer
```

So instead of your `for` loop use this (a *tested* one, and with an *improvement*):

```
for j, i in enumerate( random.sample(list(questions), 5) ):          # Slight change
     question = questions[i]
     start_time = time.time()     
     answer = input("{}. soru --> {} : ". format(j + 1, i))          # Sligth change
     if time.time() - start_time > allowed_time:
         print("   Time-out: You didn't answer quickly enough.")
         answer = ""

     if answer == question:
         correct += 1
     elif answer == "":
         blank += 1
     else:
         wrong += 1
```

Not that I slightly changed your `for` statement and the `answer = ...` for the sake of *printing correct ordinal numbers of questions* (yours were always `1.`)